# What's the difference between a Team Lead and a Director?

Tags: title, team-role, teamleader

As I reflect on my preparedness levels for a Team Lead role I'm interviewing for, I'm realizing I might be conflating Team Lead with Director. The Team Lead role I'm interviewing for would have a total of. 10 reports, some direct some indirect, and be expected to 5-10x output (with only 2x resources) within a year while overall improving marketing strategy.

I asked if this is the "director-level role" they and I had discussed in the past and was told yes, but usually, what's the difference between the titles?

Comment: Closely related (dupe?): [Is there a significant difference in the titles “Vice President” and “Director”?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/59325/73791)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My additional responsibilities beyond direct reports are  unclear and something I'll ask. That's correct, this is the role I referenced prior.

Comment: Is this an actual board member - the normal definition, or is this a marketing company where you can have people with director titles that are just senior roles above a lead

Comment: @Neuromancer the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I asked if this is the "director-level role" they and I had discussed in the past and was told yes, but usually, what's the difference between the titles?

In general, **titles and their meaning vary greatly** depending on each company and what *they* expect and how *they* define such title.

However, in this specific case, team lead and director could be separate roles held by different people. *Director* seems to be [used interchangeably with VP](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/59325/73791), whereas a Team Lead usually reports to the Director and is in charge of managing the team, etc..

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I was also told that I would report directly to the CMO but that this might get layered in the future. I'm inferring that in this case, this is not a director role and I may report to the Director of Marketing Strategy later depending on how this new Influencer Marketing team evolves, or it may evolve into a Director of Influencer Marketing role.

Comment: @John oh, sorry I misread :) pruning comments

Answer (score 1):

The two terms "team lead" and "director" could have any meaning the company wants.  I have seen team leads that were leading a team of two, and team leads leading a team of dozens. I have seen people with the title of director in a company of 10 people, and  a company of 10,000 not have anybody with that title.

Even titles such as VP can have any meaning. I have worked with companies where the jump from employee to VP was 3 levels on the org chart, and there could be several VPs in your building. In other cases where there might be a VP in your city, and they were 5 or 6 levels above the average employee.